# Active Records in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am just starting to learn ruby on rails and i have question related active record. If you want to find a record in a way that does not break the app, which one is better:

```
users = User.where(email: abc@def.com)
if users.any?
    user = users.first
else
    user = nil
end
```

OR

```
begin
     user = User.where(email: abc@def.com).first
rescue
     user = nil
end
```

can you please guide me and tell me which is better in terms of performance and the correct 'rails-way' of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call the 'first' method even if the where statement returns no results. In the case where there are no results, the first method will return nil.

We can simplify your first suggestion:

```
user = User.where(email: 'abc@def.com').first
```

Comment: Or even `user = User.find_by(email: 'abc@def.com')`.